# Reading from a txt file and writing to a struct in C

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read data in from a txt file and insert it into a struct I have. I've tried using fscanf and it compiles but crashes when I run it. I'm fairly new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

The data format is as follows

A1 6  30 4

A2 9  11 6

A3 9  30 7

A4 90 11 3

Here is what I have so far

```
      typedef struct Process
    {
        char name[3];
        int arrivalTime;
        int serviceTime;
        int priority;
    } Process;

int main(){
    Process record[MAX];
    int i, counter;   
    FILE *ifp;

    ifp = fopen("data.txt","r");

    if (ifp == NULL) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
     exit(1);
     }

     while (EOF != fscanf(ifp, "%s %d %d %d", &record[i].name, &record[i].arrivalTime,
           &record[i].serviceTime, &record[i].priority)){
           i++;
           counter;
     }

     fclose(ifp);           

     int j;
     for (j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
         printf(record[j].name, &record[j].arrivalTime,
         &record[j].serviceTime, &record[j].priority);
     }       

}
```

Comment: `counter;`. Did you mean to do `counter++;`? And you also need to initialise it to `0` before that.

Comment: Apart from that, your code is just waiting to blow up. Mainly because your buffers and arrays are fixed size but your code does not protect against overflowing any of those.

Comment: I did mean it to be counter++! I changed that and initialized it before also, still crashing on me though. :/

Comment: Then run your program in a debugger. That will tell you more in 1 minute than a whole lot of to and fro on Stackoverflow. For starters it will tell you exactly which line of code is causing the crash.

Comment: It compiles fine. When I run the executable it says it has stopped working. That's what I'm having the issue deciphering.

Comment: The debugger is not the compiler! If you are on Linux then the common debugger is `gdb`. On windows there is a debugger in the Visual Studio IDE (along with the compiler). A debugger allows you to examine the state of a running program. Learn to use it if you want to be a serious developer.

Comment: A compiler merely informs you that your code is syntactically correct. The logic is up to you, and that is where the debugger steps in. Or rather YOU step in the the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. It was a segmentation fault that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Have you also initialized i to zero? Also, you don't need to take the address of record.name.

Comment: I have i initialized to zero yes. It seems I fixed the segmentation fault, it doesn't crash. However now the console pops up and disappears instantly.

Comment: `%s` format specifier cannot take `&record[i].name`. `%s` expects a pointer to `char`. You're supplying pointer to pointer to `char`

Comment: your fscanf should look like this:  while (EOF != fscanf(ifp, "%s %d %d %d", record[i].name, &record[i].arrivalTime, &record[i].serviceTime, &record[i].priority)){

Comment: This `printf(record[j].name, &record[j].arrivalTime,&record[j].serviceTime, &record[j].priority)` is very wrong. It will print out `name` and nothing else. The first argument of `printf` should be the formatting rules just like the `fscanf` above, but that alone won't solve all of the problems. I doubt you want to print the address of `serviceTime`, so lose the `&`. It's the address-of operator.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a ton for your help. One last question, the print is only displaying the name, any idea as to why it is stopping there? Just saw your reply. Thanks so much for the help everyone.

Comment: And the console closing instantly is because there is nothing to hold the console open when the program is done. Place a breakpoint on the closing brace in the debugger or a `getchar();` right at the end to force it to wait for you.

Comment: Read up on printf: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf There are a bunch of examples at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use a buffer with some size initialized and read data from it.

```
char buffer[256];

while (EOF != fscanf(ifp, "%[^\n]\n", buffer)){
           sscanf (buffer, "%s %d %d %d", record[i].name, &record[i].arrivalTime ,&record[i].serviceTime, &record[i].priority);
           i++;
           counter++;
 }
```

Print using:

```
for (j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
         printf("%s %d %d %d \n", record[j].name, record[j].arrivalTime, record[j].serviceTime, record[j].priority);
 }
```

Comment: Cleaned it up, but it's up to you to explain to OP what the heck all that means. In its current form it's just teaching cut-and-paste Cargo Cult programming.